# Key Error: "None of --- are in the columns"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I wrote a script to scrape Yahoo Finance stock data using the [Yahoo_Fin package](https://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/)

The aim of the script is to grab company financials to be able to perform some calculations. The input to the script is a txt file with a list of company ticker symbols. The output is also supposed to be a txt with only the companies that match a certain number of established criteria.

The script does occasionally work with a small txt file (20 tickers or less) however it does sometimes give me the following error (without me changing any code)

"None of ['Breakdown'] are in the columns" with Breakdown being the index column I set for the df.

I have run the script dozens of times and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Ran it in Atom and Jupyter Notebook and still have no clue what is causing the problem. I have also updated pandas and all necessary packages.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics as stat
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import *

stock_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("test.txt", "r")]
#print(stock_list)

## The balance sheet df ##
balance_sheet = {ticker: get_balance_sheet(ticker)
                    for ticker in stock_list}

## The income statement df ##
income_statement = {ticker: get_income_statement(ticker)
                    for ticker in stock_list}


bs_data=[]

for i in range(0,len(stock_list)):
    one_ticker = pd.DataFrame(balance_sheet[stock_list[i]])
    one_ticker = one_ticker.set_index('Breakdown')
    bs_data.append(one_ticker)

#print(bs_data)

income_data=[]

#one_ticker =[]

for i in range(0,len(stock_list)):
    one_ticker = pd.DataFrame(income_statement[stock_list[i]])
    one_ticker = one_ticker.set_index('Breakdown')
    income_data.append(one_ticker)

#print(income_data)

    ## These are the balance sheet variables ##

for loop_counter in range(0,len(stock_list)):
    # Total Assets
    total_assets = (bs_data[loop_counter].loc['Total Assets'].astype(int))
    avg_total_assets = stat.mean(total_assets)
    #print(avg_total_assets)

    # Total Current Liabilities
    total_current_liabilities = (bs_data[loop_counter].loc['Total Current Liabilities'].astype(int))
    avg_total_current_liabilities = stat.mean(total_current_liabilities)
    #print(avg_total_current_liabilities)

    #Total Liabilities
    total_liabilities = (bs_data[loop_counter].loc['Total Liabilities'].astype(int))
    avg_total_liabilities = stat.mean(total_liabilities)
    #print(avg_total_liabilities)

    ## These are the income statement variables ##

    # Total Revenue
    total_revenue = (income_data[loop_counter].loc['Total Revenue']).astype(int)
    avg_total_revenue = stat.mean(total_revenue)
    #print(avg_total_revenue)

    # Operating Income
    operating_income = (income_data[loop_counter].loc['Operating Income or Loss']).astype(int)
    avg_operating_income = stat.mean(operating_income)
    #print(avg_operating_income)

    # Total Operating Expenses
    total_operating_expenses = (income_data[loop_counter].loc['Total Operating Expenses'].astype(int))
    avg_total_operating_expenses = stat.mean(total_operating_expenses)
    #print(avg_total_operating_expenses)

    # EBIT
    ebit = (avg_total_revenue-avg_total_operating_expenses)
    #print(ebit)


    ## Calculations ##

    opm = (avg_operating_income) / (avg_total_revenue)
    #print(opm)
    roce = (ebit) / ((avg_total_assets) - (avg_total_current_liabilities))
    #print(roce)
    leverage = (avg_total_liabilities) / (avg_total_assets)
    #print(leverage)

    #print("Leverage: " + str(round(leverage,2)))
    #print("OPM: " + str(round(opm*100,2)) + "%")
    #print("ROCE: " + str(round(roce*100,2)) + "%")

    ## Save to file ##

    #print(leverage)
    #print(opm)
    #print(roce)
    if leverage < 1.00 and roce >= 0.2 and opm >= 0.2:
        #print("We have a match!")
        outfile = open("results.txt", "a")
        outfile.write(stock_list[loop_counter])
        outfile.write("\n")
        outfile.close()
```

Any clues to what might be the problem??

Update #2 Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics as stat
from yahooquery import *

# Ticker input here
stock_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("test.txt", "r")]

#for stock in stock_list:
tickers = Ticker(stock_list)

# Get balance sheet
for stock in stock_list:
    #print(stock)
    bs = tickers.balance_sheet()
    bs = pd.DataFrame(bs)
    bs = bs.set_index('endDate')
    #print(bs)


## Balance sheet variables to extract ##

# Total Assets
    total_assets = bs['totalAssets']
    avg_total_assets = stat.mean(total_assets)

# Total Current Liabilities
    total_current_liabilities = bs['totalCurrentLiabilities']
    avg_total_current_liabilities = stat.mean(total_current_liabilities)

# Total Liabilities
    total_liabilities = bs['totalLiab']
    avg_total_liabilities = stat.mean(total_liabilities)

## Get income statement ##
    inst = tickers.income_statement()
    inst = pd.DataFrame(inst)
    inst = inst.set_index('endDate')

## Income statement variables to extract ##

# Total Revenue#
    total_revenue = inst['totalRevenue']
    avg_total_revenue = stat.mean(total_revenue)

# Operating Income
    operating_income = inst['operatingIncome']
    avg_operating_income = stat.mean(operating_income)

# Total Operating Expenses
    total_operating_expenses = inst['totalOperatingExpenses']
    avg_total_operating_expenses = stat.mean(total_operating_expenses)

# EBIT
    ebit = (avg_total_revenue-avg_total_operating_expenses)

## Parameters ##
    opm = (avg_operating_income) / (avg_total_revenue)
    roce = (ebit) / ((avg_total_assets) - (avg_total_current_liabilities))
    leverage = (avg_total_liabilities) / (avg_total_assets)

## Save to file ##
    #print("Hello!")
    if leverage < 1.00 and roce >= 0.2 and opm >= 0.2:
        #print("Hello")
        outfile = open("yahoo_query_results.txt", "w+")
        outfile.write(stock)
        outfile.write("\n")
        outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Is it possible to input a text file with a list of tickers as the input to Tickers method?

Comment: Sure, just do what you did above with stock_list and pass that to the Ticker class.

Comment: When I use    tickers = Ticker(stock_list), the code works but does not produce an output file for some reason. Can't seem to understand what Ticker. API object?

Comment: Depending on which method you utilized, it will return a dictionary or a data frame. It won’t output anything to a file. What is the code that you’re using?

Comment: I am using the Update #2 Code bit in the original post.

Comment: See update below

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. However, with certain input txt files I get the following:     
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loc'. Is this because some of the stock tickers have missing data maybe?

Comment: It's probably one of two things: (1) the ticker couldn't be found or (2) the ticker does not contain any of that specific data.  When nothing is found, a dictionary is returned:   `{'ticker': 'Quote not found for ticker symbol: ticker'}`, which is why you're receiving that error.

Comment: I see, thought so. Is there a way to handle errors, that is skip problematic tickers and continue with the for loop? I did a try and except block but it does not produce a file output.

Comment: You should be able to use a try / except block.  Put all your code inside the try block and catch the AttributeError after your if statement.  Or you can do an if statement to see what type of data bs is:  `if isinstance(bs, dict)` or `if isinstance(bs, pd.DataFrame)`